# Python: Adress sub-tuples in tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, mysql, database

Hy!
As a complete beginner to python I wonder how I fetch a tuple-element inside a tuple of tuples - i.e. the result of

```
results=cursor.fetchall()
```

gives a tuple

```
((row1_value1,row1_value2,...),(row2_value1,row2_value2..),)
```

I know that

```
for id in results:
    print id
```

or

```
results [i]
```

accesses each row as a whole.

But how do I directly access a tuple - value inside the tuple, i.e. row2_value3 ???

I helped myself with the following code, but isn´t there a possibility to give a exact "adress", such as
results [i,sub-i] ??

```
for id in results:
    a=results[i]
    i=0
    for x in a:
        print a[i]
        i+=1
```

I want to use fetchall, just to learn how to do things in python- i want to have the whole datbase in python and work with that.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code might be easier to work with a dictionary data structure and store the tuples as values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results[0][1]
```

accesses the second (1) element from the first (0) row (`row1_value2` in your case). The lists in Python are 0-indexed.

The same way, `row2_value3` is `results[1][2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `results[row][field]`.

Comment: ah! I knew it would be possible :) I was googling around and didnt get it... Thanks a lot! :) - BTW is there a list of possible functions to a tuple, such as "id" is one, another thing I couldnt find in the docs? Thx!!